# Sharing BigQuery's cache across multiple users

Tags: google-bigquery

As I understand it, BigQuery's [caching](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data?hl=en#querycaching) mechanism is on a per user basis. But we'd like to be able to share the cache on something like a project/dataset/table level.

For example, John & Mary both work on the same Google project `XYZ`. They love using BigQuery, and both query the table `Bar` in dataset `Foo` i.e. `XYZ:Foo.Bar` to get beautiful insights from their data.

John logs in and writes a query against `XYZ:Foo.Bar` which takes 10 seconds to execute. A few minutes later Mary logs in and composes the **exact** same query on `XYZ:Foo.Bar`. It also takes 10 seconds, but she does not get a cache hit.

Is there anything that can be done to share the query cache across users i.e. on a project/dataset/table level? Or have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't share cache across users for privacy reasons - but it could be an interesting feature request to propose: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/.

An alternative you could implement today is a proxy that would connect to BigQuery on behalf of your users with a service account. For example, you get the BigQuery native cache and an application level cache when using http://demo.redash.io. Same with [Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) - as it uses a service account by default, results are cached for users in the same project.

Comment: Thanks a mill Felipe!